# Ignoring comments (characters after a certain character) when reading lines

Tags: python-3.x, file

does any of you know a good scheme to get rid of comments when reading in a file line by line in Py3? I don't want to use regex if possible at all.

Assume the content of the file looks similar to this:

```
#first comment
while prime_count < n:#second comment
        for number in range(2, current):
            if current % number==0:#third comment
                break
```

I usually read the content via:

```
file = open(refname, "r")
lines = file.readlines()
print(lines)
```

The output should be:

```
    while prime_count < n:
            for number in range(2, current):
                if current % number==0:
                    break
```

Any hint towards a certain direction would be helpful. The roughly 500 files will be in the order of 5000 characters.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps a sample file data with expect output would be helpful.

Comment: It's given. Both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to bram-vanroy to guiding me to strip/split - haven't thought of that before.

```
with open(refname, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split('#', 1)[0]
        print(line)
```

will do what I want. Splitting the line at the pound sign and only keeping the first part.

Another version, that gets rid of multiple blank lines, but uses regex:

```
with open(refname) as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split('#', 1)[0]+"\n"
        line = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n',line)
        if line.strip():
            list.append(line)
```

Comment: This is a bad idea because it is plausible that you have the string character `#` in your code somewhere. You'll break the code completely.

Comment: Okay. I think I never used '#' for something else than outcommenting. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: There is no way to be sure. Without an actual parser. I don't even understand why you want to do this, so you can do whatever fits your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just `open` a file - it needs to be closed, too. Best to use a context manager `with`:

```py
with open(refname, "r") as file:
    # only keep those lines that do not start with a pound sign (after removing any whitespace)
    lines = [l for l in file.readlines() if not l.lstrip().startswith("#")]
print(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks. Closing the file is a valid point. Your code ignores only lines that START with '#', so only the first comment. I want to get rid of all comments unfortunately.